# Appending additional stopwords to nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english') list or updating as a set returns NoneType object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried appending to the stopwords from nltk (both as list and set). However, it returns a NoneType object. I have used the following approaches:

1. Extending a list:

   stopword = list(stopwords.words('english'))

   stopword = stopword.extend(['maggi','maggie','#maggi','#maggie'])

   print(stopword)

   > None
2. Updating a set

   stopword = set(stopwords.words('english'))

   stopword = stopword.update(set(['maggi','maggie','#maggi','#maggie']))

   print(stopword)

   > None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stopwords.words('english') is already a list so you don't need to convert into the list again.
At the place of using list.extend() which is giving None type output, we can just create another list and add it to stopword.
So following code will complete the task and get you the output

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopword = list(stopwords.words('english'))
l = ['maggi','maggie','#maggi','#maggie']
stopword = stopword + l
print(stopword)
```

Comment: I added the `list` command just for good measure as the above method isn't working

Comment: `stopword = stopword.extend(('maggi','maggie','#maggi','#maggie'))` will still assign `None` (returned result of extend function) to `stopword`

Comment: My bad... So at the place of using list.extend() which is giving None type output, we can just create another list and add it to stopword. I have edited my answer accordingly.